# AWS S3 CopyObjectAsync fails with key does not exist, but get/put succeeds

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I fought with this for several hours and never found the solution.  Here's the scenario:

```
var copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest
{
    SourceBucket  = s3Event.S3.Bucket.Name,
    SourceKey  = s3Event.S3.Object.Key,
    DestinationBucket  = OutputBucketName,
    DestinationKey  = s3Event.S3.Object.Key,
};

var deleteRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = copyObjectRequest.SourceBucket,
    Key = copyObjectRequest.SourceKey,
};

await S3Client.CopyObjectAsync(copyObjectRequest);
await S3Client.DeleteObjectAsync(deleteRequest);
```

S3Client.CopyObjectAsync throws the error: "The specified key does not exist." (S3Client.DeleteObjectAsync is never reached.)

However, the following code works (for the same values):

```
var request = new GetObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = copyObjectRequest.SourceBucket,
    Key = copyObjectRequest.SourceKey,
};

var response = await S3Client.GetObjectAsync(request);
var tempPath = $"{Guid.NewGuid():D}";
await response.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(tempPath, false, CancellationToken.None);

var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = copyObjectRequest.DestinationBucket,
    Key = copyObjectRequest.DestinationKey,
    FilePath = tempPath,
};

var putResponse = await S3Client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);

if (putResponse.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    var deleteRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = copyObjectRequest.SourceBucket,
        Key = copyObjectRequest.SourceKey,
    };

    await S3Client.DeleteObjectAsync(deleteRequest);
}
```

For brevity I removed almost all error checking, logging, etc. but if requested I'm happy to share the full function.

Note that this is running in a C# Lambda Function, using Core 2.0.

- I've ruled out security as the second set of calls requires the same permissions (I believe) as the CopyObject call does (please do correct me if I'm wrong).
- There's no doubt the object is at the bucket and key specified as the second set uses the exact same structure.
- The key doesn't exist in the destination bucket.
- Both the source and destination buckets have the same permissions.
- There are no special characters in the key (sample keys that I've tested are "/US/ID/Teton/EC2ClientDemo.zip" and "testkey").
- The files I'm testing with are tiny (that sample file is 30Kb).
- I've tried it with and without a CannedACL value in CopyObjectRequest (I don't think it should require one for my purposes, all the files it's moving around are private).
- I've validated that all buckets are in the same region (USWest2).

I can't figure out why CopyObjectAsync fails.  I've tried digging down through the disassembled code for CopyObjectAsync, but it's called so indirectly I didn't get very far.  At this point my best guess is that it's a bug in CopyObjectAsync.

Any suggestions would be appreciated,
Thanks for reading!

Additional: I want to make it clear that this works from the regular AWSSDK library (either CopyObjectAsync or CopyObject), it only fails in the Core 2.0 async call CopyObjectAsync in the Lambda environment.

Comment: Object keys in S3 do not begin with a `/`.  Unfortunately, I believe some of the SDKs allow this, and quietly remove it in some cases... but it is wrong.  It may be that the copy method doesn't remove it, but the get method does, thereby masking the error in one case, while allowing it to work, in the other. The problem is that when bugs like this are introduced in code that gets widely deployed, where the bug has no impact if your code is right, there's a tendency not to fix it, because it would break a lot of code that works only because of side-effects of the broken behavior.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Can you point me to documentation that says that there is this limitation in S3 keys?  While the AWS S3 console and many other programs will treat keys with slashes in them as "directories" under the hood S3 keys are not paths, just strings, and therefore there should be no limitation at all on what characters are used in the key (in fact, you can easily break many tools by using funky Unicode characters in keys, but they don't break the API).
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys

Comment: The shortest path to troubleshooting this is probably to check the bucket logs to see what is being seen by the service.  I ran into an issue with this not too long ago, and it was one of those things that once I figured it out, it was extremely obvious... but I was hitting my head on the desk for a while before the light bulb came on.  It was node.js but they all use the same underlying API to communicate with S3.  Note that "this is a test key" is actually an edge case test, because of the spaces.  Verify without them, ASCII only, to limit the possibility of anything unexpected.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm not sure what you mean by "S3 logs."  If you mean CloudTrails, then I've tried that and there is nothing in there that seemed helpful.  I enabled monitoring both buckets and the Lambda function that I'm testing.  If you mean something else, please direct me to that.

Comment: I assure you, spaces in object keys are a *potential* edge case because of the way S3 handles them on the wire. It's perfectly fine to use them, just not while you're trying to troubleshoot.  Access logs for S3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you for pointing out the other S3 logging function, I hadn't seen that.  It gave me the information that I needed to figure out that there is definitely a bug in the Core 2.0 CopyObjectAsync function (see my answer below, if you're curious).  You were also right that the problem was the silent removal of the slash by CopyObjectAsync, but only in the Core 2.0 library, I tested copy, get, and put in both synchronous and asynchronous versions and only the Core 2.0 has this bug.  I would still like to see where you found documentation that initial slashes are not allowed.

Comment: Initial slashes are not strictly disallowed, but they are effectively wrong because they are semantically nonsensical.  The reason is because the root of a bucket is not `/`, it is *(empty-string)*.  In a URL, the object key starts *after* the leading `/`.  The REST URL for the key `foo` is `example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/foo`, while the URL for the key `/foo` is actually `example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com//foo`.  You see the problem, I presume?  The key `/foo` is, by S3 reckoning, inside a (pseudo-)folder named *(empty-string)* because the first byte of the key is a `/` delimiter.

Comment: Side note: spaces can get you in trouble because the REST API converts both `+` and `%20` to `+` on the way in, treating them both as ASCII 0x20 `[SP]`, and actually will fetch such an object either way.  You can only store a `+` as `%2B`, but browsers don't send a `+` in the path as `%2B`.  The Lambda event will report spaces as `+` so you have to change them back to a space before url-decoding the key.  I assume this dates back to the days of the SOAP (retch) API, and is far too entrenched to be properly fixed.  AWS is very good about not breaking API client code.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You are making several assumptions here.  FIrst that a key is a directory and has a "root" (it's not), second that the S3 files will be accessed by URL.  Our key names are the way they are for our own internal purposes, web access is specifically denied for security.  We only ever access these buckets via the C# Core 2.0 API.  So, while I get your point that *if* we were accessing these buckets via URLs we would have to take into account the extra slashes, we aren't and won't ever so shouldn't care.  The same comment goes towards spaces.

Comment: My comments are based on typical usage of S3, so I stand by those assumptions, even if they don't apply to you.  If you never access the objects via URL, then these behaviors may have no impact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I figured it out and it is definitely a bug in the core 2.0 CopyObjectAsync().  Here's the scenario:

We are using keys that have slashes at the beginning, an example would be '/US/ID/Teton/EC2ClientDemo.zip'.  When I turned on S3 logging (thank you @Michael-sqlbot) what I saw was this:

```
[13/Jul/2018:17:44:18 +0000] 34.221.84.59 arn:aws:sts::434371411556:assumed-role/LambdaFunctionCreation/TestFunction 489A5570C2E840AC REST.COPY.OBJECT_GET US/ID/Teton/EC2ClientDemo.zip - 404 NoSuchKey
```

As you can see the CopyObjectAsync() function stripped off the first slash before making the call.  Get, Put, and Delete handle these particular keys just fine (and I tested this in the non-Core library and both the synchronous and asynchronous versions of CopyObjectAsync() handle the keys just fine as well).

What I had to do to fix it was the following:

```
var copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest
{
    SourceBucket  = s3Event.S3.Bucket.Name,
    SourceKey  = "/" + s3Event.S3.Object.Key,
    DestinationBucket  = OutputBucketName,
    DestinationKey  = "/" + s3Event.S3.Object.Key,
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl,
};
```

Note the added slashes on the SourceKey and DestinationKey?  Without those the keys are mangled.

Here is the complete final code:

```
var copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest
{
    SourceBucket = s3Event.S3.Bucket.Name,
    SourceKey = s3Event.S3.Object.Key,
    DestinationBucket = OutputBucketName,
    DestinationKey = s3Event.S3.Object.Key,
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl,
};

try
{
    await s3Client.CopyObjectAsync(copyObjectRequest);
}
catch (AmazonS3Exception ase) when (ase.Message.Contains("key does not exist"))
{
    try
    {
        // If this failed due to Key not found, then fix up the request for the CopyObjectAsync bug in the Core 2.0 library and try again.
        var patchedCopyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest()
                                       {
                                           SourceBucket  = copyObjectRequest.SourceBucket,
                                           SourceKey  = "/" + copyObjectRequest.SourceKey,
                                           DestinationBucket  = copyObjectRequest.DestinationBucket,
                                           DestinationKey  = "/" + copyObjectRequest.DestinationKey,
                                           CannedACL = copyObjectRequest.CannedACL,
                                       };

        await s3Client.CopyObjectAsync(patchedCopyObjectRequest);
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception)
    {
        // Rethrow the initial exception, since we don't want a confusing message to contain the modified keys.
        throw ase;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are an angel sir!